# Render wordpress on Laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, laravel-4

the following is the index.blade.php of laravel app.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en-GB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <?php 
        global $wp_rewrite;
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
        // require_once (app_path().'/libraries/wp-config.php');
        // require (app_path().'/libraries/wp-load.php'); 
        require (app_path().'/libraries/wp-blog-header.php'); 
        // require ('../app/libraries/wp-blog-header.php');
    ?>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0" />
        <title> @yield('title') </title>
    </head>
    <body @yield('bodyclass')>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="primary-menu" class="dropdown-menu-wrap">

            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'menu',
                'menu_id' => '',
                'fallback_cb' => false
            )); ?>

            </div>
```

trying to call the menu of the existing wordpress application. while the config.php is directly download from the existing wordpress, wp_include is fresh download from new wordpress files. same to wp-blog-header, wp-load, and wp-setting.

I not sure why keep on pop out the error of Call to a member function main() on a non-object. Tested all the available solution but failed.

```
function wp( $query_vars = '' ) {
global $wp, $wp_query, $wp_the_query;
$wp->main( $query_vars );

if ( !isset($wp_the_query) )
```

Comment: `Call to a member function main() on a non-object.` usually means that  the variable being used is not an object, in this case `$wp` does not seem to be the wordpress object, is the wordpress framework present in this script

Comment: @Patrick Evans, is there any possibility to consume the function? I mean wp_nav_menu from external site of Wordpress. Thx

Comment: How you are mixing in Blade and Wordpress?

Comment: @fideloper, yep. i'm trying to..

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do that as well and I think this could be an answer: https://github.com/swt83/laravel-wordpress/blob/master/readme.md

Best regards!;-)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using WordPress Functions in "blade", you can pass it to variable and can call that into blade.

```
<?php   
//In controller
 $args = array(
            array('theme_location' => 'primary',
                'container' => false,
                'menu_class' => 'menu',
                'menu_id' => '',
                'fallback_cb' => false,
            'echo' => false
        ));
        $data['menu'] = wp_nav_menu($args);
?>

//In blade
{{$menu}}
```

For Detailed, You can go through: [Wordpress+Laravel](http://grossi.io/2014/working-with-laravel-4-and-wordpress-together/)